# Is there a simpler way to do this? How can I get rid of one of my while loops?

Tags: c, while-loop, pi

For my CS assignment we were asked to create a program to approximate pi using [Viete's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te%27s_formula). I have done that, however, I don't exactly like my code and was wondering if there was a way I could do it without using two while loops.

(My professor is asking us to use a while loop, so I want to keep at least one!)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  double n, x, out, c, t, count, approx;
  printf("enter the number of iterations to approximate pi\n");
  scanf("%lf", &n);

  c = 1;
  out = 1;
  t = 0;
  count = 1;
  x = sqrt(2);

  while (count<=n)
  { 
      t=t+1;

      while (c<t)
      { 
          x=sqrt(2+x);
          c=c+1; 
      }

      out=out*(x/2);
      count=count+1; 
  }

  approx=2/out;
  printf("%lf is the approximation of pi\n", approx);
}
```

I just feel like my code could somehow be simpler, but I'm not sure how to simplify it.

Comment: Why do you feel like it could be simpler? Which part of the program exactly are you saying is the problem you are concerned with? It is hard to answer very broad questions like this on Stackoverflow because it would mostly be an opinionated answer. 
Also, remember to try and format your code so it is spaced well and easy to read, that can make it all the more difficult to follow the code when it is hard to read.

Comment: why not using one For loop?

Comment: I think your code is fine. Personally, I'd work on the formatting (it looks like someone else has fixed it for you) and perhaps on giving your variables more descriptive names. Then, if you feel like it, you could read up on increment operators, compound assignments, and `for` loops.

Comment: @Karl I don't like the fact that I am using two while loops. I was wondering if there was a way to code this program using only one, rather than the two I am currently using.

Comment: Also, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be worth a mention.

Comment: looking at the formula it seems to naturally call for 2 loops. Maybe somebody could do fancy (un readable!) code that doesnt but I would not worry.

Comment: @Iarn as mentioned you could replace either of your while loops with a for loop, but that would not change the logic of the code because it would still loop the same amount.

Comment: You could unroll the inner loop yourself, but your code would not be nearly as succinct then. :O)

Comment: You could use one while loop by putting what's in the outer loop in an if statement with a break?

Comment: One improvement - `n` and `count` could be `int`

Comment: Could not resist, sorry: https://ideone.com/Q0v9dW . Converted to single `while` loop trivially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider how many times the inner loop runs in each iteration of the outer loop

- on the first iteration, it does not run at all (c == t == 1)
- on each subsequent iteration, it runs exactly once (as t has been incremented once since the last iteration of the outer loop).

So you could replace this inner while with an if:

```
    if (count > 1) {
```

once you do that, `t` and `c` are completely unnecessary and can be eliminated.

If you change the initial value of `x` (before the loop), you could have the first iteration calculate it here, thus getting rid of the `if` too.  That leaves a minimal loop:

```
out = 1;
count = 1;
x = 0;
while (count<=n) {
    x=sqrt(2+x);
    out=out*(x/2);
    count=count+1; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I just feel like my code could somehow be simpler, but I'm not sure how to simplify it.
>
> I don't like the fact that I am using two while loops. I was wondering if there was a way to code this program using only one, rather than the two I am currently using

Seems simply enough to use a single loop.

OP's code, the `while (c < t) loop`, could be replaced with `if (c < t)` and achieve the same outcome.  The loop is only executed 1 or 0 times.  With an adjustment of initial `c` or `t`, the loop/block could executed exactly once each time.  Thus negating the test completely.

A few additional adjustments are in `Viete()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double Viete(unsigned n) {
  const char *pi = "pi   3.141592653589793238462643383...";
  puts(pi);
  printf("m_pi=%.17f\n", acos(-1));
  double term = sqrt(2.0);
  double v = 1.0;
  while (n-- > 0) {
    v = v * term / 2;
    printf("v_pi=%.17f %u\n", 2 / v, n);
    term = sqrt(2 + term);
  }
  puts(pi);
  return 2 / v;
}

int op_pi(unsigned n) {
  unsigned c = 1;
  unsigned t = 0;
  unsigned count = 1;
  double out = 1;
  double x = sqrt(2);

  while (count <= n) {
    t = t + 1;

    // while (c < t) {
    // or 
    if (c < t) {
      x = sqrt(2 + x);
      c = c + 1;
    }

    out = out * (x / 2);
    count = count + 1;
    printf("%lf is the approximation of pi %u\n", 2 / out, count);
  }

  double approx = 2 / out;
  printf("%lf is the approximation of pi\n", approx);
}

int main(void) {
  op_pi(5);
  Viete(5);
}
```

Output

```
2.828427 is the approximation of pi 2
3.061467 is the approximation of pi 3
3.121445 is the approximation of pi 4
3.136548 is the approximation of pi 5
3.140331 is the approximation of pi 6
3.140331 is the approximation of pi
pi   3.141592653589793238462643383...
m_pi=3.14159265358979312
v_pi=2.82842712474618985 4
v_pi=3.06146745892071825 3
v_pi=3.12144515225805197 2
v_pi=3.13654849054593887 1
v_pi=3.14033115695475251 0
pi   3.141592653589793238462643383...
```

Additional minor simplifications possible.